# How to Combine Webelement and Select to make reusable function.?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**I'm a Novice in Selenium.!**

I have created 2 class files using **Selenium Java** where trying to implement all basic functionalities completely re-usable, I'm here trying to pass arguments from **inputClass.java** to **mainClass.java** to **dropDown()** within, calling 2 methods **chooseElement()** and **ddElement()**.

Where **chooseElement()** is a **WebElement** and **ddElement()** is **Select**, all i need is to pass values from **inputClass.java** to get the dropdown working. Someone just correct me in my code.

Thanks in advance

Page Source Code:

```
<div id="autocomplete_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 300px;" title="">
<a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>Selenium</span>
<div>
<b/>
</div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
```

mainClass.java

```
public class methods {

static WebDriver driver;

public static void wait(int w) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(w, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static Actions getAction() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    return action;
}

public static WebElement chooseElement(int x,String path){

    WebElement webElement = null;

    switch (x){
    case 1:         
        webElement=driver.findElement(By.id(path));
         break;
    case 2:
        webElement=driver.findElement(By.className(path));
        break;
    case 3:
        webElement=driver.findElement(By.linkText(path));
        break;
    case 4:
        webElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)); 
        break;
    case 5:
        webElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(path));
        break;
    case 6:
        webElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName(path));
        break;
    }           
    return webElement;      
}


    public static Select ddElement(WebElement webElement, int dx,Object dindex){

    Select select = new Select(webElement);

    switch (dx){
    case 1:     
        System.out.println("case 1");
        select.selectByVisibleText((String) dindex);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("case 2");
        select.selectByValue((String) dindex);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("case 3");
        select.selectByIndex((int) dindex);
        break;  
    }           
    return select;      
}

public static void mouseOver(int x, String path) throws InterruptedException {      
    WebElement mO=chooseElement(x, path);        
    getAction().moveToElement(mO).perform();        
}

public static void textBox (int x, String path, String text) throws InterruptedException {          
    chooseElement(x, path).sendKeys(text);      
    getAction().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
    }

public static void click(int x, String path) throws InterruptedException {          
    chooseElement(x, path).click(); 
}

public static String getTxt(int x, String path) throws InterruptedException {               
    String returnText = chooseElement(x, path).getText();
    return returnText;
}
public static void dropDown(int x, String path, int dx,Object dindex) throws InterruptedException {
    try {               
        WebElement webElement=chooseElement(x, path);
        ddElement(webElement,dx,dindex); // Value index                  
        }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

    }
}
}
```

inputClass.java

```
public class OrderRabbit extends methods {
@Test
public static void main (String arg []) throws  IOException, InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-2.47.1\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();                
    driver.get("https://www.qatest.com/");

    // Login
    mouseOver(4, ".//*[@id='Login_block']/a/span");
    getAction().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
    wait(60);
    textBox(1, "username","******@gmail.com");
    textBox(1, "password","******");        
    click(4, ".//*[@id='loginForm']/button");

    //Assertion
    /*String str = getTxt(1, "firstNameIdProfile");
    Assert.assertNotEquals(str,"Login");*/

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //Click DropDown
    //click(1,"autocomplete");      
    dropDown(1,"autocomplete_chosen",1 ,"Course");
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: hey, i think you can use one more line like WebElement myEle=chooseElement(int x,String path); after go for dropDown(myEle,1 ,"Course"); just given like please check arguments correctly and try it

Comment: So you turned something simple to read like `driver.findElement(By.Id("someId"))` into something arcane like `chooseElement(1, "someId")... why? There's really no reason to create a wrapper for the core API in this case. You should really spend some time reading some basic Java/programming tutorials.

Comment: @JeffC, some companies prefer to provide a keyword driven framework for automation. In this way error handling and logging can be taken care easily and people with less programming knowledge can create simple scripts.

Comment: @Sighil : Thanks, This works well

Comment: @JeffC : Thanks for your advice, I'll keep it in mind. FYI: I already mentioned that i'm a NOVICE. I just got into this forum to learn programming as initial step

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of the following line in the ddElement method.

```
select.selectByIndex((int) dindex);
```

You cannot cast a object to primitive type int. Use Integer instead.

```
select.selectByIndex(((Integer) dindex).intValue());
```

However, a better way for writing the method class will be as follows.

Main Class

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Methods {
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    protected static final int ID = 1;
    protected static final int CLASS = 2;
    protected static final int LINKTEXT = 3;
    protected static final int XPATH = 4;
    protected static final int CSS = 5;
    protected static final int TAGNAME = 6;

    protected static final int VISIBLETEXT = 1;
    protected static final int VALUE = 2;
    protected static final int INDEX = 3;

    public static void wait(int timeOutInSeconds) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static Actions getAction() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        return action;
    }

    private static WebElement chooseElement(int byStrategy, String locatorValue) {
        By by = null;

        switch (byStrategy) {
        case ID:
            by = By.id(locatorValue);
            break;
        case CLASS:
            by = By.className(locatorValue);
            break;
        case LINKTEXT:
            by = By.linkText(locatorValue);
            break;
        case XPATH:
            by = By.xpath(locatorValue);
            break;
        case CSS:
            by = By.cssSelector(locatorValue);
            break;
        case TAGNAME:
            by = By.tagName(locatorValue);
            break;
        }
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }

    public static void mouseOver(int byStrategy, String locatorValue) throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement mO = chooseElement(byStrategy, locatorValue);
        getAction().moveToElement(mO).perform();
    }

    public static void textBox(int byStrategy, String locatorValue, String text) throws InterruptedException {
        chooseElement(byStrategy, locatorValue).sendKeys(text);
        getAction().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
    }

    public static void click(int byStrategy, String locatorValue) throws InterruptedException {
        chooseElement(byStrategy, locatorValue).click();
    }

    public static String getTxt(int byStrategy, String locatorValue) throws InterruptedException {
        String returnText = chooseElement(byStrategy, locatorValue).getText();
        return returnText;
    }

    public static void dropDown(int byStrategy, String locatorValue, int selectStrategy, Object strategyValue)
            throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            WebElement webElement = chooseElement(byStrategy, locatorValue);

            Select select = new Select(webElement);

            switch (selectStrategy) {
            case VISIBLETEXT:
                System.out.println("case 1");
                select.selectByVisibleText((String) strategyValue);
                break;
            case VALUE:
                System.out.println("case 2");
                select.selectByValue((String) strategyValue);
                break;
            case INDEX:
                System.out.println("case 3");
                select.selectByIndex(((Integer) strategyValue).intValue());
                break;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

InputClass

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OrderRabbit extends Methods {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-2.47.1\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.qatest.com/");

        // Login
        mouseOver(XPATH, ".//*[@id='Login_block']/a/span");
        getAction().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
        wait(60);
        textBox(ID, "username", "******@gmail.com");
        textBox(ID, "password", "******");
        click(XPATH, ".//*[@id='loginForm']/button");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click DropDown
        // click(ID, "autocomplete");
        dropDown(ID, "autocomplete_chosen", VISIBLETEXT, "Course");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The `ddelement` method can be included in the `dropdown` method as there is no advantage in separating it out.

Comment: kindly accept the answer so that the question can be closed